# @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity is deprecated in the new spring boot 3.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I use Spring Boot 3.0, and when I work on security configuration, I get a warning that the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` is deprecated.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
```

With what do I replace can replace `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` in Spring boot 3.0?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use now:

```
@EnableMethodSecurity
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html)

Note that you can avoid using `prePostEnabled = true`, because by default is `true`.

```
boolean prePostEnabled() default true;
boolean jsr250Enabled() default false;
boolean proxyTargetClass() default false;
```

Comment: I was searching for this.Thanks you.